# DirectX9: delay between present() and actual screen update

Tags: delay, direct3d, timing, directx-9

My question is about the delay between calling the present method in DirectX9 and the update appearing on the screen.

On a Windows system, I have a window opened using DirectX9 and update it in a simple way (change the color of the entire window, then call the IDirect3DSwapChain9's present method). I call the swapchain's present method with the flag D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT during a vertical blank interval. There is only one buffer associated with the swapchain.
I also obtain an external measurement of when the CRT screen I use actually changes color through a photodiode connected to the center of the screen. I obtain this measurement with sub-millisecond accuracy and delay.

What I found was that the changes appear exactly in the third refresh after the call to present(). Thus, when I call present() at the end of the vertical blank, just before the screen refreshing, the change will appear on the screen exactly 2*screen_duration + 0.5*refresh_duration after the call to present().

My question is a general one:

- in how far can I rely on this delay (changes appearing in the third refresh) being the same on different systems ...
- ... or does it vary with monitors (leaving aside the response times of LCD and LED monitors)
- ... or with graphics-cards
- are there other factors influencing this delay

An additional question:

- does anybody know a way of determining, within DirectX9, when a change appeared on the screen (without external measurements)

Comment: Had the exact same sort of question today. I was trying to write a simple program to test audio/video sync with a capture, and my audio is 1-2 frames "early", but I'm guessing it is due to the buffering happening with directx and not with the simple Beep I'm using.

Comment: @aggieNick02 interesting, how many buffers are you using? and do you, by any chance, know what kind of delay is to be expected when using the simple Beep()? If it had very short delays, one might be able to use this as a test on different devices to see how many frames the screen lags behind, by calling present(), then waiting x number of frames before calling beep, and then changing x until beep and screen are synchronized.

Comment: I'm using 1 back buffer and dx11. As to the beep delay, unfortunately I don't have any good info on that. For your setup, how do you know when the call to Present() is executed to start your timing?

Comment: I keep polling the swapchain's GetRasterStatus method, to know when a vertical blank interval was entered, then I call present with the donotwait flag set, which will be successful when no other present call was made during that blank interval. I take a timestamp immediately after that, and then wait for the external sensor to signal that the screen updated. Dx11 doesnt have the GetRasterStatus method anymore, but it has a class IDXGIOutput with a method WaitForVBlank() you can use to achieve the same end.

Comment: Is the external sensor then connected to the same PC to timestamp when the screen updates? Just curious how you get a common time basis between your executing code and the sensor change. If it is connected to the same PC, how much can you trust the sensor change timestamp?

Comment: The photodiode is first connected to an Arduino Uno, which does nothing but poll the sensor and send the resulting byte to the PC via true serial connection. While I run the graphical program updating the screen and timestamping the present method returning, I run a second thread which contiously polls the serial connection and timestamps the incoming bytes with the same timer method. For both timestamps I use the Windows API's timeGetTime() with resolution set to 1 ms using timeBeginPeriod(). There is a little trick to getting both timeGetTime()s to be synchronous but that's basically it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the setup. Sounds solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of variables at play here, especially since DirectX 9 itself is legacy and is effectively emulated on modern versions of Windows.

> You might want to read [Accurately Profiling Direct3D API Calls (Direct3D 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234.aspx), although that article doesn't directly address presentation.

On Windows Vista or later, once you call `Present` to flip the front and back buffers, it's passed off to the Desktop Windows Manager for composition and eventual display. There are a lot of factors at play here including GPU vendor, driver version, OS version, Windows settings, 3rd party driver 'value add' features, full-screen vs. windowed mode, etc.

In short: Your Mileage May Vary (YMMV) so don't expect your timings to generalize beyond your immediate setup.

If your application requires knowing exactly when present happens instead of just "best effort" as is more common, I recommend moving to DirectX9Ex, DirectX 11, or DirectX 12 and taking advantage of the DXGI [frame statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173060.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for that info. There's two questions I have regarding your post: 1) when I use a full-screen window, I understand the Desktop Windows Manager would be circumvented; would that ameliorate my problem? 2) I had looked into frame statistics before, but the microsoft msdn page info did not give me the impression frame statistics would address my needs; how can I derive actual presentation time from the frame statistics structure?

Comment: DWM is not disabled by "exclusive fullscreen", and the exact code path depends a lot of the particular version of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody stumbles upon this with a similar question: I found out the reason why my screen update appears exactly on the third refresh after calling `present()`. As it turns out, the Windows OS by default queues exactly 3 frames before presenting them, and so changes appear on the third refresh. As it stands, this can only be "fixed" by the application starting with Directx10 (and Directx9Ex); for Directx9 and earlier, one has to either use the graphics card driver or the Windows registry to reduce this queueing.

Comment: Are you sure your code wasn't just trying to do vsync with multiple [BackBufferCount](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58481/does-directx-implement-triple-buffering/#58483)?